# What's the correct to display a graph from a table row?

Tags: usability

I'm working on a data cleaning feature. In this feature, users are *required* to assign each columns in a dataset be an input or an output. *Optionally*, users will be able to rename columns, ignore columns and view a histogram.

To do this, I have developed an initial mockup which has a table that has a column to display column names and a second column for column type. Third columns for renaming. At the top, I have a bulk action button for assigning multiple inputs/outputs.

**Problem:** We cannot display the histogram for each column on load because that would take a long time, so we only load one at a time. The issues is that it's difficult to keep track of the column in the table while viewing the histogram below it. Is there a better way to display the histogram?

[image: https://share.balsamiq.com/c/e2cGbfV3fCfpvMPFSpvVnW.png]

Comment: Asking for ideas how to improve a design is off-topic for this site. Can you elaborate on what the actual problem is with the current design focussing on one aspect? Ask multiple question on this site of you want to solve multiple problems in the design.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. I updated this post with a more focused question.